# Neo4j 6 Spring boot 2.4 migrate driver session query

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to migrate to neo4j 6. Whats the equivalent of this method in neo4j6?
The Result here contains: {ref=Employee.... etc, so the actual Java objects.

```
//org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session is autowired
@GetMapping("/companies/{companyId}/refs")
public Result getCompanyRefs(@PathVariable final String companyId)
{
    String query = "MATCH (company:Company)-[ref]-(refObj) where company.id=\"" + companyId + "\" RETURN company,ref,refObj";
    return this.session.query(query, Collections.emptyMap());
}
```

I tried with the new neo4j driver like so:

```
//org.neo4j.driver.Driver is autowired 
    @GetMapping("/persons/{personId}/refs")
public Result getPersonRefs(@PathVariable final String personId)
{
    String query = "MATCH (person:Person)-[ref]-(refObj) where person.id=\"" + personId + "\" RETURN person,ref,refObj";
    return this.driver.session().run(query, Collections.emptyMap());
}
```

but this gives a Result which is not convertable to my @Node (entity) classes. The previous version gave a Result which contained the actual java objects(mapped to classes).
the result here is:Record<{person: node<7>, ref: relationship<8>, refObj: node<0>}>
Basically the main thing is: i need the nodes mapped to java objects. But i need them via a cypher query, because i need to do some things on the (Result) Nodes before deleting the relationships between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it turns out it  does give back the things i need.

```
Result result = this.getPersonRefs(id);
        result.list().forEach((entry) -> {
```

The problem was that for example neither `entry.get("refObj").asObject()`, nor `asNode()`  actually gave back what i thought it was supposed to give back.

**The Solution:**

```
entry.get("refObj").asMap()
```

this gives back the actual properties of the object. Then you just need to convert it to MyClass.class with an ObjectMapper.